# Routing for multiple profile views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, sti

I no have idea how to implement display of the multiple user's profile.
I use STI inheritance to for few types of person.

**What I want?**

I want to create the simplest routing for each type of person, and possibility to display and edit profile for each type of person. Now I have this:
[image]

I thought about profile view(backend_people_profile) only for people model, and update_profile for each type. Is it correct? Now I have too many repetitive paths.

**routes.rb**

```
namespace :backend do
      resources :managers, except: [:new, :create] do
        get '/profile', to: 'people#show_profile'
      end

      resources :clients, except: [:new, :create] do
        get '/profile', to: 'people#show_profile'
      end

      resources :receptionists, except: [:new, :create] do
        get '/profile', to: 'people#show_profile'
    end

      resources :trainers, except: [:new, :create] do
        get '/profile', to: 'people#show_profile'
      end

      resources :lifeguards, except: [:new, :create] do
        get '/profile', to: 'people#show_profile'
      end
  end
```

Comment: Let me get this straight, you have a Person class with subclasses and want to have a cleaner way? You also have a form on the profile? You can use `form_for(resource, as: 'person', url: profile_url)` to avoid some duplication.

Comment: Also consider adding a profiles controller to stick closer to REST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
namespace :backend do
  resources :people

  [:clients, :receptionists, :trainers, :lifeguards].each |type| do
     get type, to: "people#index"
  end
end
```

I would start with the simplest possible setup. In this case you would only have the full CRUD routes for the base `people` type. This avoids cluttering your API with a ton of routes that perform the exact same thing.

For each subtype you simply have an index action which is somewhat like:

```
GET /people?type=trainer
```

You may want to consider if you really need separate routes for profiles - unless you need two significantly different representations you can get by with the conventional CRUD routes:

```
GET|POST         /people
GET|DELETE|PATCH /people/:id
GET              /people/:id/new
GET              /people/:id/edit
```

The other case would be an app where users are CRUD:ed by admins where you need a separate interface for the regular user signup. In that case you might to do it like so:

```
namespace :backend do
  resources :people
  [:clients, :receptionists, :trainers, :lifeguards].each |type| do
     get type, to: "people#index"
  end
end

# public facing route
resources :registrations, only: [:new, :create, :show, :edit, :update]
```

Comment: Although on a side note using STI in this case is probably a misstake - you are building in a limitation that a user can only belong to a certain category - don't expect reality to conform to your model! Instead you would use a has many relation between users and roles. This is a tried and true way to solve the same issue.